# How to get rendomise value with condition with PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of about 100 different random number like this:

```
$numbers=array(10,9,5,12, ..... .... ... ...);
```

now i want to make an array of random numbers from this array so that `addition of selected numbers will be my given number`. example: i may ask to get array of numbers such that, `if i add all numbers it will be 100`.
i am trying to do it in this way,

```
function rendom_num ($array,$addition)
{
//here is the code

}
print_r (rendome_num ($numbers,100));
```

i am not able to fiend the code for last 3 days!

Comment: You're probably after the [Knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem), applied after shuffling the array.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Something like this should work. The breakdown is commented so you know what it's all doing.

```
function Randomizer($number = 100)
        {
            // This just generates a 100 number array from 1 to 100
            for($i=1; $i <= 100; $i++) {
                    $array[]    =   $i;
                }
            // Shuffles the above array (you may already have this array made so you would need to input into this function)
            shuffle($array);
            // Assign 0 as base sum
            $sum    =   0;
            // Go through the array and add up values
            foreach($array as $value) {
                    // If the sum is not the input value and is also less, continue
                    if($sum !== $number && $sum < $number) {
                            // Check that the sum and value are not greater than the input
                            if(($sum + $value) <= $number) {
                                    // If not, then add
                                    $sum    += $value;
                                    $new[]  =   $value;
                                }
                        }
                    // Return the array when value hit
                    else 
                        return $new;
                }
            // If the loop goes through to the end without a successful addition
            // Try it all again until it does.
            if($sum !== $number)
                return Randomizer($number);
        }

    // Initialize function
    $test   =   Randomizer(100);

    echo '<pre>';
    // Total (for testing)
    echo array_sum($test);
    // Array of random values
    print_r($test);
    echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: This code works fine but when i refreshed a few time i have got `Warning:  array_sum() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in E:\software\html\index.php on line 29`

Comment: This algorithm has the potential of not stopping.

Comment: though i have to change this code but it helped me a lot :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please use shuffle-

```
<?php
$numbers = range(1, 20);
shuffle($numbers);
foreach ($numbers as $number) {
    echo "$number ";
}
?>
```

**[php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php)**

Comment: here each time i will get different number, but i need to take then in such a way that addition of all numbers will be a fixed number. lets say it 100.

Answer (score 0):

can use [shuffle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27097849/3928375) as @chatfun said or can try [array_rand](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) if want only some random values from your array

```
$value= array("Rabin","Reid","Cris","KVJ","John");
$rand_keys=array_rand($value,2);
echo "First random element = ".$value[$rand_keys[0]];
echo "<br>Second random element = ".$value[$rand_keys[1]];
```

Comment: my question is not about shuffle , it is about the value after shuffle.